# How to display Crystal Report?

Tags: asp.net, database, crystal-reports, connection-string

I am getting this error while displaying crystal report.
what do i need to do.

**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**


Code i am using is as follows :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=~/App_Data/Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");        
    DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT        ID, Name, Dept, Salary FROM            dbo.Table2", con);
    da.Fill(ds.View2);
    ReportClass myReportObject = new ReportClass();
    myReportObject.ResourceName = "CrystalReport1.rpt";        
}
```

Comment: the `DataSource` seems to be incorrect.

Comment: It's not a crystal report error, it's SQL Server error. Check your connection string and the database file

Comment: When I Use 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);        

it says : Database logon failed.

I dont want to use username n Password. What should i do?

Comment: try username and password instead of Integrated Security=True

Comment: well the username and password if of the server. u will have specify that. remove integrated security once you specify that.

Answer (score 0):

I Think your Crystal report you are trying to display has been made under an another Connection string has an another Server name. pass Server name and database name separately to the report. the code will helpful.

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables ;

        cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "YOUR SERVER NAME";
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "YOUR DATABASE NAME";

       // if sql server authentication mood

        crConnectionInfo.UserID = "YOUR DATABASE USERNAME";
        crConnectionInfo.Password = "YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD";

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables ;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```